# JIT stands for Just In Time compiler. what is the meaning of compiler here

Tags: java

Can we compare JIT with inline function? how It works and why we call it compiler, when JVM is combination of Java Interpreter and OS.

Comment: Have you done your research before asking?

Comment: Yes. But I did not get any exact answer why do we call it compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JIT "compiles" bytecode to native machine code which can then be run directly on further calls. In practice, many JVMs (e.g. Hotspot) will JIT-compile the same bytecode multiple times, adapting the optimization settings based on observed performance data (and on new information such as subclasses being loaded which override previously-inlined code).

> when JVM is combination of Java Interpreter and OS.

I wouldn't describe a modern JVM that way. In particular, while most JVMs still include an interpreter of some form, the majority of the time that Java code is running, it isn't being interpreted in the traditional sense.

Comment: Thanks Jon. It seems more clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just-In-Time (JIT) compiler is a component of the JRE that improves the performance of the code at run time.

From Implementation Perspective you can say like this

1.When any class is compiled the Byte code is generated for the same.

2. Now this Byte code is read by the Interpreter (Here JIT comes into picture.)

How JIT compiles code at **"just in Time"**-->

When any method gets called **first time**.The JIT compiler compiles the bytecodes of the same method into native machine code.Now whenever this method is called again at any time; JVM calls the compiled code of that method directly (**From native Machine code**)instead of interpreting it every time the method is called.

How to enable JIT-->
The JIT compiler is enabled by default, and is activated when a Java method is called.You can disable the JIT compiler using the **-Djava.compiler=NONE** option to the Java VM.

Comment: Thanks Shailesh. It's very helpful.